# блок схема цикла while с++

Tags: c++, блок-схема

подскажите пожалуйста как на блок схеме должен выглядеть цикл while(1) . Блок с действием стоит оставить пустым или как?

Comment: если 1==1 то повторить

Comment: Скорее зацикленным, с проверкой условия и выходом. Что-то типа ->A->B->C и из С обратно в А, а из B - выход наружу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так (если в цикле будет выполняться действие):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в цикле не выполняется какое-либо действие, то блок с действием можно оставить и пустым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]